# count no. of set bits of each number in a range and then sum it up

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Count no. of set bits in each number in a range and then display the total sum.
Input-
2
1 1
10 15
Output-
1
17
I am getting time limit exceeded problem also I am not getting any output for the problem. Could anyone tell me the error in my code.Thank you

```
import java.util.*;
public class counBitsInRange {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Q = sc.nextInt();
        int[] res = new int[Q];
        for(int i=0;i<Q;i++)
        {
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            res[i] = countbits(a,b);
        }

        for(int j=0;j<res.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(res[j]);
        }
    }

    private static int countbits(int a,int b)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
        {
            while(i>0)
            {
                count+=(i&1);
                i=i>>1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer` class has the method `bitCount` returning the number of one-bits, rewrite your method `countbits` using the java library class method like below:

```
private static int countbits(int a,int b) 
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
      count += Integer.bitCount(i);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bug: Both the for loop and the body inside while loop changes the `i` value, which sometimes makes the loop go forever. Keep them separate.

```
 private static int countbits(int a,int b)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int j=a;j<=b;j++)
    {
        int i = j;
        while(i>0)
        {
            count+=(i&1);
            i=i>>1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

> ```
> for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
> ```

No matter what you put inside that loop, it will not scale well to large ranges, and the ranges could be two billion long.

An alternative algorithm is:

1. Use a clever trick to count the total number of set bits in the range [0, b + 1] (exclusive of the endpoint)
2. Use the trick again to count the total number of set bits in the range [0, a]
3. The difference between them is the total number of set bits in the range [a, b + 1]

For example, in code:

```
static long countSetBitsInRange(int a, int b)
{
    return countSetBitsUpTo(b + 1) - countSetBitsUpTo(a);
}

static long countSetBitsUpTo(int n) 
{ 
    int power = 1;
    long cnt = n >> 1;  
    while ((1 << power) <= n) 
    { 
        long totalPairs = n >> power; 
        cnt += (totalPairs >> 1) << power;
        if ((totalPairs & 1) != 0)
            cnt += n & ((1 << power) - 1);
        power++; 
    } 
    return cnt; 
}
```

Based on a trick from [Count total set bits in all numbers from 1 to n](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-total-set-bits-in-all-numbers-from-1-to-n).